# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Python Array and Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

this is my code. but I have the above Error. I searched before but didn't help me to find the answer. What is not correct in this code?

```
import numpy as np 
import math

def sigmoid(x):
    s = np.array(None)
    for i in x:
        np.append(s,(1/(math.exp(-x)+1)))

    return s

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
sigmoid(x)
```

---

```
<ipython-input-31-8e002c20e792> in sigmoid(x)
     17     s = np.array(None)`
     18     for i in x:
---> 19         np.append(s,(1/(math.exp(-x)+1)))
     20     return s
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: is math.exp meant to be np.exp? that works on nd arrays

Comment: I tested it. but it returns none! and i don't know why.and why math.exp doesn't  work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `math.exp` by `np.exp`.  The former is a Python built-in which only understands scalars (hence the error message).

Also note that `np.append()` returns the result, and does not modify its arguments.  So you'll need to assign the result back to `s`.  Also note that repeatedly appending to a NumPy array is an anti-pattern--you should allocate the entire array at the start.

Comment: why `math.exp` doesn't work? and why we should assign the result back to `s` in `np.append()` ? I thought that it takes the argument `s`to return the result in it.

Comment: @EshaghMoutabi NumPy arrays are immutable. The value is appended to a copy of the original and returned but you are returning the `s` not the appended copy. Also I think you meant `math.exp(-i)` but not `-x`